# Scanner object does not return intended result

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to use the `scanner` object to validate some user input. According to my requirement if user input is **100>inputs<0**  I need to provide some console output. However, the following code does not work when I enter 100/0 and provides me some empty console output. I tried to test this code block with 102 and -1 with same (empty) console output

```
public int validateScore(Scanner sc) {
        int score = 0;
        System.out.println("Please Enter Student's Score.");
        for (;;) {
            if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the score and in number");
                sc.next(); // discard
            }else if (sc.nextInt() > 100){
                sc.next(); // discard
                System.out.println("Please enter the score and in number in between 0-100 only: ");                
            }else if (sc.nextInt() < 0){
                sc.next(); // discard
                System.out.println("Please enter the score and in number in between 0-100 only: ");                
            }else {
                score = sc.nextInt();
                break;
            }
        }
        return score;
    }
```

Comment: you are reading input twice once at validation and again next on return value assignment. First read it into a variable then validate and return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not read from the `Scanner` several times. Just read the number once via `nextInt` into the variable and check it. Otherwise on every `if` branch you will be prompted for a new number.

```
public int validateScore(Scanner sc) {
    int score = 0;
    System.out.println("Please Enter Student's Score.");
    for (;;) {
        if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the score and in number");
            sc.next(); // discard
        } else {
            int nextInt = sc.nextInt();
            if (nextInt > 100) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the score and in number in between 0-100 only: ");
            } else if (nextInt < 0) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the score and in number in between 0-100 only: ");
            } else {
                score = nextInt;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is causing because of using nextInt() in the if else block . Use the method hasNextInt() and store the value in a temporary variable before validating the value .

Comment: ya was a little mistake. Thanks for the reply